# Intel HAXM: This computer does not support Execute Disable Bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, cpu, android

I am trying to install Intel HAXM on my machine and receive a message along the lines of:

> Cannot install This computer does not support Execute Disable Bit XD

Looking up my processor on the Intel ARK, it seems like Disable Bit is [supported](http://ark.intel.com/products/47663/intel-core-i3-330m-processor-3m-cache-2_13-ghz).

However, I see that it is also dependent on other factors highlighted in the asterisk on the above link. I have a Gateway NV79 and notice that Disable Bit is not an option in the systems BIOS. Does this mean I am out of luck and cannot toggle Disable Bit, and hence cannot ever get HAXM support on my machine?!

Thanks, this is in effort to speed up Android emulation.

Comment: Looking at the [Gateway support page](http://support.gateway.com/us/en/product/default.aspx?tab=5&modelId=2385) there are some BIOS updates available, although none of them refers to the Execute Disable Bit. Which version are you currently using? Something else you can check: open the Start menu, type or paste `SystemPropertiesPerformance.exe` and select the Data Execution Prevention tab. See whether the text says "Your computer's processor support hardware-based DEP."

Comment: @and31415 Yes, SystemPropertiesPerformance.exe says my hardware does not support DEP. I tried installing the BIOS updates but it looks like  my machine freezes when installing any of them. I'll keep trying but it doesn't look like DEP is listed in any of the release notes.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this trouble. The problem was that in BIOS(an old version) I wasn't finding where to enable "Execute Disable Bit" feature.

After I read the manual for my motherboard I find that to enable this feature I needed to go In BIOS - Advanced and enable the "No Execute (NX) Memory Protection" feature.

After this change I didn't face any errors.